# Why proxy_pass returns 404?

Tags: nginx

I have a working config for proxy pass as:

```
location /preprod/ {
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_redirect off;

        proxy_pass http://preprod/;
    }
```

it works well, however, for routes ends with `.svg` it returns 404 before being proxied to the `preprod` above.

why only `.svg` does not work, where could be config issue?

**EDIT**

I found that this included file was breaking the `proxy_pass` at above setting for all routes ends with `eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2` ,if I remove it, proxy_pass will fine, but why? how would I keep it for all locations and at the same time keep proxy working at location `/preprod/` ..

```
location ~* \.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

Comment: are the `.svg` paths static resources referenced by the server at `http://preprod/`?

Comment: I am not sure if I got your point, but I monitor the access.log of nginx at the preprod server, nothing is logged, so the request does not get proxied from the proxy server.

for the same route, I can access it at the preprod server successfully

Comment: @ti7 check EDIT above please